# Modify each td of dataTable with certain class

Tags: jquery, datatable

```
$('#table').DataTable().cells('.currency').data().each(function(value, index) {         
        console.log(value);
    });
```

This code print the value of each td with class `currency`.

The value is a string that contains a currency (2434 for example). I want to format it into the correct value -> 2.434,00.
So, I can get the value, format it, but I don't know how to replace the old currency with the new.

`$(this).val()` or `$(this).html()` does not work.

Comment: change your code like `$('#table').DataTable().cells('.currency').each(function(value, index) {` So `$(this)` will be your td inside of `.each` callBack

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, I did it, then `console.log($(this).val());` but I get this error: **Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined**

Comment: are you getting object in $(this) ?

Comment: @debin, with `console.log($(this).val());`? No, because I get the error first

Comment: first check does $(this) contain object or not..td's value can be get by `$(this).html()` or `$(this).text()`

Comment: @debin, How? In this way I get the error before to take $(this)

Comment: take as reference https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every()

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use the datatables API `render` method?  This would be the correct way to do it IMO.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#table > tr > td').hasClass('.currency').each(function(value, index) {         
        console.log(value);
        $(this).text(formattedValue);
    });
```

You may have to loop in this way.

Comment: As you probably know, dataTable divides the rows in pages. Your code works only with the first page. But If I browse through the pages, from the second page onwards it does not work.

Comment: @DavideFruci You may try hasClass in that case more like $('#table').DataTable().cells().hasClass('.currency')...

Comment: I don' understand, sorry

Comment: I'm sorry, can't say exactly from provided information. Can you see the value of $(this)?

Comment: I better explain my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34723591/format-currencies-when-datatable-is-created/34723697#34723697

Comment: I guess You will have to do the formatting code in paging events too.