# Format currencies when dataTable is created

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

```
var oTable = $('#table').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "aaData": jsonList,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "aoColumns": [
        {
           "mDataProp": null,
           "sClass": "control center",
           "sDefaultContent": '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/SD7Dz.png">'
        },
        { "mDataProp": "ente" }, 
        { "mDataProp": "cup" }, 
        { "mDataProp": "decreto" }, 
        { "mDataProp": "data" }, 
        { "mDataProp": "importoImpegno" }, //this is a currency
        { "mDataProp": "finanziato" }, //this is a currency
        { "mDataProp": "importoPagato" }, //this is a currency
        { "mDataProp": "importoInPagamento" } //this is a currency  
    ],
    "aoColumnDefs": [
     { "sClass": "currency", "aTargets": [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ]}
     ],
    "oLanguage": {
        "sInfo": "_TOTAL_ entries"
    },
    "aaSorting": [[1, 'asc']]
});
```

As you can see, I add `.currency` class only to the column where is a currency.
I need to format this currencies (3235 to 3.235,00 for example) and I have already the function to do that.

```
function currencyFormatIT(num) {

    if(num != null && num != "") {
        num = parseFloat(num);
        num = num
        .toFixed(2)
        .replace(".", ",")
        .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1.");
    }
    else {
        num = "";
    }

    return num;
}
```

I tried to use this method so:

```
$("table.myTable > tbody td.currency").each(function(){
    $(this).html(currencyFormatIT($(this).html()));
    $(this).css("text-align", "right");
});
```

But, it's work only with the row that appears in the **first page** of datatable:

[image: First page]

From the second page to onwards not:

[image: Second page]

If I add this code:

```
$(document).on("click", "td.currency", function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

works for all td of all page!!

1) Why?
2) If I want to call the currencyFormatIT() function like callback function (maybe in the code where I create the dataTable `.dataTable({..` how could I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fnDrawCallback` function.

```
var oTable = $('#table').dataTable({

   "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
      // Format Currency here
    }

}
```

You can check the [documentation](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks) for more details about possible callback functions.

Comment: Ok, but what should I pass to currencyFormatIT() function? How can I tell him: "Call currencyFormatIT() for each td with class currency"?

Comment: Works. But the currencyFormatIT(), now, is called every time I change the page or I sort the columns. And this is not right. There is any callback function that is called only once?

Comment: @DavideFruci is not it what you want ? When you change the page, you need to format currency for new data on that page. But if you want to just call it once, you can use fnInitCallback function.